# undefined local variables in templates

Tags: backbone.js

I'm following along with this tutorial (in french only) https://github.com/k33g/articles/blob/master/2011-08-14-BB-VIEWS.md which uses underscore templates with Backbonejs.

The tutorial says to put this template below in index file.

```
      <script type="text/template" id="doc-template">
            <span><%= id %></span>
            <span><%= title %></span>
            <span><%= test %></span>
            <span><%= keywords %></span>
       </script>


   <div id='doc-container'></div>
```

I'm putting it in index.html.erb, however, the tutorial author is not using rails. It's necessary for me to use erb because I also include page specific content using rails content_for helpers.

When I try to view the page, I get an undefined local variable or method error

```
undefined local variable or method `id' for #<#<Class:0x007fd9c3a133b8>:0x007fd9c5066d90>
```

If I remove those variables from the templates it's still not rendering content to the page.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong to render the data?

**Other Backbone view related code**

The tutorial initializes and renders a view in the appropriate container...

```
        el : $('#doc-container'),
        initialize : function() {
            this.template = _.template($('#doc-template').html());


            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.model.on('change', this.render);

        },

        render : function() {
            var renderedContent = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
            $(this.el).html(renderedContent);
            return this;
        }
```

**Update**

I'm having the same problem when I follow the tutorials instructions for a collection view. It throws an error for underscore's each method

```
undefined local variable or method `_' for #<#<Class:0x007fd9c3a133b8>:0x007fd9c2c78a78>
```

template in index.html.erb

```
<script type="text/template" id="docs-collection-template">
    <ol>
      <% _.each(docs, function(doc) { %>
        <li><%= doc.id %> : <%= doc.title %></li>
      <% }); %>
    </ol>
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding an ejs template inside of an erb template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716557/embedding-an-ejs-template-inside-of-an-erb-template)

Comment: @Soldier.moth it's not a duplicate because that question's not about underscore templates

Comment: Actually, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514922/rails-with-underscore-js-templates

Comment: @Lukas your answer provides more information than the other page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Underscore is using the same syntax for templating as ERB, so it is conflicting. You need to tell Underscore to use a different syntax. From the Underscore docs:

> If ERB-style delimiters aren't your cup of tea, you can change
>   Underscore's template settings to use different symbols to set off
>   interpolated code. Define an interpolate regex to match expressions
>   that should be interpolated verbatim, an escape regex to match
>   expressions that should be inserted after being HTML escaped, and an
>   evaluate regex to match expressions that should be evaluated without
>   insertion into the resulting string. You may define or omit any
>   combination of the three. For example, to perform Mustache.js style
>   templating.

So, somewhere in your JavaScript code, before you compile the template, add the following code:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate : /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
    escape : /\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g,
    evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
};
```

Then, anywhere in your template where you have `<% %>`, change it to `{{ }}`, change `<%= %>` to `{{= }}`, and change `<%- %>` to `{{- }}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<%%= variable %>`. Rails output for this will be `<%= variable %>`.